# Can't create a abstract class mock in another file

Tags: php

I have an abstract class defined in my project that I want to run tests on.

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use phpDM\Connections\Adapters\ConnectionAdapterInterface;

include(__DIR__ . '/../../../src/Connections/Adapters/ConnectionAdapterInterface.php');

class TestConnection { }

class ConnectionAdapterInterfaceTest extends TestCase
{

    function testCreateConnection() {
        $interface = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('ConnectionAdapterInterface');
        $interface->method('createConnection')
            ->willReturn(new TestConnection());
        $connection = $interface::createConnection();
        $this->assertInstanceOf(TestConnection, $connection);
    }

}
```

The ConnectionAdapterInterface is a (poorly named) abstract class:

```
abstract class ConnectionAdapterInterface {
    abstract public static function createConnection(array $config);
}
```

However, no matter what I do, I keep getting the error `Class "ConnectionAdapterInterface" does not exist.`. In the sample above, I have both a `use` and `include`, though I also tested with each one at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify. It's poorly named, but `ConnectionAdapterInterface` is an abstract class. It's an interface in behavior, not in function.

Comment: include before use.

Comment: and try to use the full name or ConnectionAdapterInterface::class